# Laravel Export data into Excel file need to be modified

Tags: php, excel, laravel, laravel-5, export

I want to download 2 user's data from tables, I want to generate excel file of that data.

here is the download function for only one data table called **registerdetails**.

```
public function export(){
    $items = registerdetails::all();
    Excel::create('General Trainee Details', function($excel) use($items){
        $excel->sheet('Sheet 1', function($sheet) use($items){
            $sheet->fromArray($items);
        });
    })->export('xlsx');
}
```

I need this controller to be modified get datas from **registerdetails** and **bankdetails**. if anyone can help me to get this solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
public function collectionexport_all(){
    $items = registerdetails::join('bankdetails', 'bankdetails.id', '=', 'registerdetails.id')->get();
    $itemsArray = []; 
     foreach ($items as $item) {
        $itemsArray[] = $item->toArray();
    }

    Excel::create('Full Details', function($excel) use($itemsArray){
    $excel->sheet('Sheet 1', function($sheet) use($itemsArray){

        $sheet->fromArray($itemsArray);

    });

})->export('xlsx');
}
```

Comment: For large data this will may not work

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you want to achieve.. But I hope this helps.

The Excel Library you're using (hoping it's maatwebsite/excel or its like) can make use of Eloquent queries or Query Builder like so:

```
public function export($id){

    Excel::create('General Trainee Details', function($excel) use($id){
        $excel->sheet('Sheet 1', function($sheet) use($id){
            $query= registerdetails::select(['registerdetailscolumn_1', 'registerdetailscolumn_2')->leftjoin('bankdetails', 'registerdetailscolumn_id', '=', 'bankdetailscolumn_id')->where(registerdetailscolumn_id, '=', $id);
            $sheet->fromModel($query);
        });
    })->export('xlsx');
}
```

Of course, knowing you can provide and pass along whatever employee's id it is.

you can export one table on one sheet and another table on another sheet like so:

```
    public function export(){

        Excel::create('General Trainee Details', function($excel) use($id){
            $excel->sheet('Sheet 1', function($sheet){
                $query= registerdetails::all();
                $sheet->fromModel($query);
            });
            $excel->sheet('Sheet 2', function($sheet){
                $query= bankdetails::all();
                $sheet->fromModel($query);
            });
        })->export('xlsx');
    }
```

Comment: what i need is need to registerdetails and bankdetails are two separate data tables so that i need to download these two data into a single excel file

Comment: If what you wish is selecting two tables and placing them on a single sheet, take a look at sql's *Union*

Comment: bro can we start a chat here